# Cakephp save Session to db after login

Tags: session, cakephp, save, session-variables

On my site (Cake 2.x), users can add favorites.
When the user is logged in, it works like a charm.

If the user is not logged in, it saves the favorites to a session-array.

I'm now struggeling, on how to save the session-favorites to the db after a user logs in.

For now, my session array looks like this:

```
$sessiondata = array('item_id' => $id, 'title' => $fitem['Item']['title'],'slug' => $fitem['Item']['slug']);
```

For my database, I only need the $id and the User.id (after logged in). How can i save the entries to the db after login()?

My join-table contains the fields: item_id and user_id

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while, but I finaly got this working. Here it is:

In my AppController, I redirected the user to my items controllers afterlogin() action.

```
public $components = array(
                      'Auth'=>array(
                            'loginRedirect'=>array(
                                   'controller' => 'items', 'action' => 'afterlogin'),
                      )));
```

Then in my ItemsController, I added the afterlogin() function:

```
public function afterlogin(){
        $favors = $this->Session->read('favorites');//get favorites stored in Session
        $this->loadModel('Item2user');//Load my join-table model
        foreach ($favors as $favor){
            //search for existing favorites
            $found = $this->Item2user->find('all', array(
                    'conditions' => array('item_id =' => $favor['item_id'],
                                    'user_id =' => $this->Auth->user('id'))
                    ));

            if($found){
                //the entry is already in the db, ->do nothing
            }
            else {
                //now save the entry to the join-table
                $this->Item->create(array(
                   'Item' => array('id' => $favor['item_id']),
                   'User' => array('id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))
               ));
               $this->Item->save();
            }
        }
        $this->redirect('/');
    }
```

Hope this helps anybody..

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set the data to your model, and then save it like so:

```
$this->Item->create(array(
    'item_id' => $sessiondata['item_id'],
    'title' => $sessiondata['title'],
    'slug' => $sessiondata['slug']
));
$this->Item->save();
```

That should save the record to the database.

Comment: I don't want to save the "Item", I want to save "item_id" and $this->Auth->user('id') to my item_user (join)table.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this on `UsersController`'s login action. After checking `if($this->Auth->login())` and before `$this->redirect()` rather than redirecting to another controller.