# Save many habtm associations in one query

Tags: cakephp

I have `User` model and `Speciality` model. `Speciality HABTM User`.

Given `speciality_id` and array of `user_id` I would like to add many users to the given speciality. So far I tried:

```
foreach($users as $user_id) {
    $data[] = array(
        'Speciality' => array('id' => $this->Speciality->id),
        'User' => array('id' => $user_id),
    );
}
if(!empty($data)) {
    $this->Speciality->saveAll($data);
}
```

But it saves only ONE row in `specialities_users` table, not all of the associations... My goal can be achived jus with big insert into specialities_users table with (speciality_id,user_id) pairs but I want to achieve this in Cake.

Comment: You can always creat a model for the specialties_users table (SpecialtiesUser) and insert the data using that model, although there are other options, this will probably best the most effective way if you need to insert a long list :)

Comment: Can find more details about what @thaJeztah is talking about by looking for 'hasManyThrough' - and I agree w/ him

Answer (score 0):

Look at my answer to this question, basically the same thing.

You have to create the array (without create it will update), check if it's already in the database -and if not, save it.

Look here:

[Cakephp save Session to db after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854806/cakephp-save-session-to-db-after-login)